# Can I write a regex expression where one symbol matches twice?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm matching words with regex in javascript. The following expression uses whitespace to separate the potential matches:

```
/(\W)(foo)(\W)/g
```

This works most of the time, but it fails when there are two matches separated by a single space. (e.g. "foo foo") I think this is because the space that separates them is the last `\W` of the first match and the first of the second.

Is there any way to modify this expression to work in this edge case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript regexes have lookahead, so you can probably do something like this:

```
/(\W)(foo)(?=\W)/g
```

I don't think lookbehinds are available, but there are [other techniques that have the same effect](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript).

Of course, this is functionally different, in that the lookahead doesn't capture, so it depends on the nature of your problem. The main point here it not that it doesn't capture, but that it doesn't *match*; thereby avoiding your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\b` instead of `\W`. It matches a zero-width *word boundary* (a boundary between a `\w` and a `\W` or the start/end of the string, while `\W` matches a character which may not exist at the start or end of a string.

Comment: I thought this had worked, but I made a mistake whilst testing. Here's a JSfiddle with my original approach and your suggested modification: http://jsfiddle.net/tdwright/7c7xe/3/

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do there. Both approaches look the same to me.

Comment: The top one uses \W as I was doing before. The bottom one uses \b as you suggest, but doesn't match anything.

Answer (score -2):

Give this a try, I think it will work for you:

```
/(\W)(foo| )(\W)/g
```

This will tell the regex to match `foo` or `whitespace` between the two `\W`s.

Comment: This isn't what I want to happen. Matching the space in between two nonword symbols isn't useful to me.